# Javascript - How to achieve show hide for an HTML section on basis of a value matching any of the tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to achieve something like this

```
<div id="121" tags="single,multi,binary">HTML Section</div>

<div id="122" tags="single,binary">HTML Section 2</div>

<div id="123" tags="binary">HTML Section 2</div>
```

Within javascript if i have a value "binary" it should show all three.

If I have value for a variable as single it should display 1st and second.

I know how to show hide the div. I just want to know if i can add user defined attribute to div and pull its value to match. If not , is there an alternate design to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('[tags*=single]')
```

But I would advice you to use `data-tags`

`*=` is contains prefix selector.

With pure javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[tags*=single]") // returns NodeList
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to achieve this using javascript only. I am not much comfortable with jquery.

Comment: @VivekVermani If you don't want jQuery answers, I would suggest not adding the jQuery tag to your question.

Comment: @Jason P - I am ok with the JQuery answer but what i meant that i will prefer JS. I was not sure if its achievable using JS , thats why included JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could change tags to classes, -> class="single multi binary"

Then use class selectors in jquery. -> $('.single').each(function(){ /* Code Here */ });

Then use jquery addClass and removeClass to push and pull attributes. -> $(element).addClass('hex');